# how to get position of deleted Firestore Data that have been deleted from console (outside source) to update Or notify the adapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have this app that someone can delete his document at any time so if he deletes the document I want every other user to get updated the document has been removed and remove the document from the listView, it's more like a Food Ordering app so the user order could be taking by another Driver so the document will no longer be available for other users, I want to update the recyclerView Whenever a user deletes a document, so how to get the position without clicking how to detect that change to get the position, Sorry if I couldn't explain much I'm Using Groupie Adapter

```
val ref = firestore.collection("orders").whereNotEqualTo("userUid", uid)

        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

        ref.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error != null){
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            value?.documentChanges?.forEach {
                if (it.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                        val userUid = it.document.data.get("userUid") as String
                        val userPhone = it.document.data.get("phone") as String
                        val userName = it.document.data.get("name") as String
                        val time = it.document.data.get("time") as String
                        val marketName = it.document.data.get("marketName") as String
                        val amount = it.document.data.get("amount") as String
                        val storeimgUrl = it.document.data.get("storeImg") as String
                        val order = it.document.data.get("order") as String
                        val userImg = it.document.data.get("userImg") as String
                       

                        adapter.add(DriverOrders(userUid, userPhone, userName, time, marketName, amount, storeimgUrl, order, userImg))
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                if(it.type == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED){

// here Wher I'm trying to get the position of deleted Or removed data
                if (it.document.id == DriverOrders.docId){
                        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(it.oldIndex)
                    }
                    
                }
            }

            recyclerview_driverorders.adapter = adapter

        }

class DriverOrders(val userUid: String, val userPhone: String,
                   val userName: String, val time: String,
                   val marketName: String, val amount: String, val storeimgUrl: String, val order: String,
                   val userImg: String):Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {

override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.driver_row
    }

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        viewHolder.itemView.driverorders_sName.text = marketName
        viewHolder.itemView.driverorders_order.text = order
        viewHolder.itemView.driverorders_time.text = Date
        
        Picasso.get().load(storeimgUrl).fit().into(viewHolder.itemView.driverorders_sImg)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the shared code? Do you have any errors?

Comment: it does remove the item but the row still in the adapter so I can't really say, so if I switch to another fragment and come back it will be gone @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you sure you are using notifyItemRemoved and passing the right index?

Comment: that is what I'm asking @AlexMamo I don't know exactly how to get the index or the position of the items in the adapter, and I don't know if the code that I shared is the right way to do it

Comment: Have you tried to log its value and see if it corresponds with the correct one? Most likely you are not notifying the adapter about the correct position.

Comment: do you know how to get that correct position cause that is what I'm here for

Comment: it shows only -1@AlexMamo not the correct one

Comment: So that's the problem. You need to step through the debugger and see why you get the -1.

Comment: I still need to get the position First @AlexMamo